# Make [reactive-forms] a synonym of [angular-reactive-forms]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [reactive-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-forms) tag has 413 questions as of now, [402 of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactive-forms%5D+is%3Aquestion+angular) mention **Angular** either in the title or the body. Its excerpt reads:

> Questions about Angular Reactive Forms(not template-driven forms). Use this tag for questions related to reactive-forms. Please mention the version of the angular used where you see the issue.

And [angular-reactive-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-reactive-forms) has 3587 of them, its excerpt is almost the same as that of [reactive-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-forms).

> Questions about Angular Reactive Forms, an Angular technique for creating forms in a reactive style. Use this tag for questions which are not specific to an individual version of Angular.

I understand that [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) has reactive forms too, but we have [flutter-reactive-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-reactive-forms) tag for questions about them.

Apparently there is no difference between these tags. Please make [reactive-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-forms) a synonym of [angular-reactive-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-reactive-forms).

Comment: I just looked and it looks like the two tags have been marked as synonyms. I personally think the difference is that [reactive-forms] are about the abstract idea of a reactive form, like [booleans] are, and less about a framework, like [angular-reactive-forms] is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the synonym got created by the community, with the system awarding the "creator" prize to [Paul Samsotha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/paul-samsotha).

I've gone ahead and merged the tags now, so marking this as complete.